# no result SQL subquery

Tags: sql

I'm not able to find out what am doing wrong the below query.

```
SELECT RP, MIN(EP) EP 
FROM (
    SELECT EP, 300000/(row_number() over(order by EP desc)) RP
    FROM (
        SELECT MAX(Value) EP 
        FROM XX 
        WHERE ID = 936 
        GROUP BY YEAR
    ) T1
) T2 
WHERE RP in (10,100,1000) 
GROUP BY RP 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Please tag which DBMS are you using and also why you say that you are doing something wrong (error? expected row not being selected? etc.)

Comment: without knowing your data table is it possible why not returning value

Comment: you are missing the parenthesis for row_number()

Comment: SELECT EP, 300000 / (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EP DESC))

Comment: I think there's no problem by the last edit.

Comment: You are Grouping by Year without specifiying it in the innermost select. That looks wrong. SQL Server I am guessing. Here's a typical example: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Without knowing what you want to do, there is no where to even begin answering.

Comment: Thank you Daniel...It worked.